# Is it permissible for a brother to lie in sister's laps

Tags: halal-haram

I'm confuse about this matter. I want to know if it is permissible for a brother to lie his head in his sister's laps. Like when we go on long journey, my brother keeps a cushion on my laps and lie on it. I don't know if it permissible or not

Comment: If he does it for lust, then it would not be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

In islam, there is absolutely nothing wrong for a brother to occasionally touch, cuddle, hug, or kiss his sister out of affection and brotherly love. They have sacred mahram relationship.

A man kissing his mahram woman is sunnah and recommended thing to do, according to both Sunni and Shia traditions:-

1- Narrated 'Aishah:"I have not seen anyone closer in conduct, way, and manners to that of the Messenger of Allah in regards to standing and sitting, than Fatimah the daughter of the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)." She said "Whenever she would enter upon the Prophet (ﷺ) he would stand to her and kiss her, and he would sit her in his sitting place. Whenever the Prophet (ﷺ) entered upon her she would stand from her seat, and kiss him and sit him in her sitting place. [source](https://sunnah.com/urn/737600)

1- Aishah said, “The Prophet once kissed Fatimah on the neck. I told him, ‘O Prophet, you treat Fatimah in a way that you do not treat others.’ The Prophet said, ‘O ‘Aishah, whenever I take interest in the Paradise, I kiss her on the neck.’[Source](https://www.al-islam.org/prophets-attitude-towards-children-and-youth-muhammad-ali-chenarani/part-1-prophets-attitude-towards)

Answer (score 0):

It's very disturbing to see the answers written. A sister, a mother, mother's sister all these kind of relationships are mahram. There is no harm in touching each other for reasons such as that mentioned by the questioner. The prophet used to kiss his daughter even after her marriage. This is out of love to her which is perfectly fine. When your mind isn't dirty, it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score -3):

It is not permissible that a brother or a sister can lie on each others lap because it is Haram. As it is said that at the age of 7 the girls should be seperated by his father and brother as well they have to maintain distance in physical touch

Comment: This post would profit from evidences that support your claims.

Answer (score -5):

Assalamualaikum warahamtullahi wabarkatahu....
"A man(young) asked prophet(pbuh) that can he kiss her wife while fasting. The prophet(pbuh) replied,"NO you can't."
A man(old) asked the same question but this time prophet replied,"yes you can."
'Bcz young one may do sex after kissing cz of attraction and naturally but old man can't.'
So sister......
In my opinion 
If any of you or your brother having a 0.1% of attraction or any prohibited emotion then you can't....
But if you can't think about that and 100% confirmed that your brother is same as you then it may permitted...
I Hope you'll don't mind it wrong...
Sorry if any mistake or anything...

Answer (score -5):

Yes, if they’re under 12-15. Also, if they’re very close and do really care then yes.

Comment: Adulthood in Islam is determined by the onset of puberty and not by an age.